# What is the relationship between current flow and low AC voltages within electrolyte solutions

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

I have recently been trying to find references or textbooks which may explain the principles of electrical current conductance within an electrolyte solution when low AC voltages are induced. Does anyone have specific expertise or knowledge into this area and may be able to explain or direct me to the right resources or authors? Thanks!

Comment: Search for molar conductivity and ion mobility. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_conductivity

Comment: @Poutnik, molar conductivity is measured at really high frequencies. I think the OP might benefit from electrochemical impedance spectroscopy. Search this term and you might useful info.

Comment: @M. Farooq I do not suppose really high frequencies, as high frequency phenomena start to occur, like reactance of electrodes and different ion behavior in dielectric layer, compared to the bulk solution.